# Calling function by name using dlsym in iOS

Tags: ios, dlopen, dlsym

Can't I call a function by name in iOS? I have a C function called `getstring`. I am calling it as follows:

```
void* handle = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW);
if (handle)
{
fp func = dlsym(handle, "getstring");
if (!func)
    responseField.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:dlerror()];
else {
    char* tmpStr = func();
    responseField.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tmpStr];        
}
}
else {
responseField.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:dlerror()];
}
```

When this executes, `responseFiled.text` is set to `dlsym(...): symbol not found`. This means `dlopen` works but not `dlsym`. I dumped the symbols in the binary using `nm` and saw that `_getstring` is present. I checked the [manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/dlopen.3.html) for `dlsym` and it says I should not add an underscore to the name. Adding it does not solve the issue anyway. What am I doing wrong?

I had asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954361/calling-a-function-by-name-input-by-user) about calling functions by name in Objective-C and then tried it successfully on a Mac following the answers, so this problem seems to be specific to iOS.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is that dlopen is not supported on iOS, even if you statically link your libraries. You *should* be able to use

```
dlsym(RTLD_SELF, "getstring");
```

because RTLD_SELF means 'start looking in the image that called dlsym'. Based on how you're using dlopen() it should accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually had some successful experiences in a case similar to yours. I used `dlsym(RTLD_MAIN_ONLY, "getstring")` to get the function pointer.

Note that your `getstring` symbol must be suitable for dynamic linking: this can be checked using

```
nm -m <application>
```

Your symbol must be `external` (not `non-external`).

I'm not yet too sure about the procedure to ensure that symbols are marked as `external`.